# Why is my light path shader drawing these cross shapes?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, lighting, glass, caustics

I was trying to make a dispersive caustics shader in Cycles by making a rainbow-gradient glass shader and then mixing it with a normal white glass shader.  I fiddled with the light path node for a while to make it so the camera sees a completely white glass object, while the light that scatters from it is rainbow.  I got this:

[image]

But when I rendered it, I noticed these interesting grooves on top of a cube:

[image]

Any idea what's causing these grooves?  How can I get rid of them?  Is there a better way to make the rainbow-colored shader not show in render?  I'm not fully understanding why taking the maximum of camera ray and transmission depth makes the rainbow color invisible, but it works.

On a side note - what can I do to make the icosahedron have less dark spots in it, asides from increasing max bounces?

Comment: Can't reproduce your grooves.  One potential cause is doubled geometry.  Got a file?  This way of rendering your rainbow is appropriate, but it's kind of an unrelated question-- I think most people around here would rather there be one question per question.  (Plus, if you ask too many questions, some people that can answer one question will skip it because they can't answer *all* the questions.)

Comment: Hmmm ok - I included the shader graph for clarity.  In any case, here's a link to my .blend file: https://blend-exchange.com/b/n0qKrApS

Comment: The file didn't show a rendered preview for me, don't know why (versions?) so I copy/pasted to a fresh file and duplicated rendering settings.  Your floor is z-fighting with the bottom face of your cube: they both occupy the **exact** same plane, overlapping, and so rays may strike the plane directly or may strike the inside (backface) of the cube, it's a crapshoot.  Move the plane down or the cube up by an infinitesimal amount.

Comment: I see, thanks!!  I'm fixing that right now